# Violin - Notation for writing sliding fingers?

Tags: notation, violin

On the violin, you slide your fingers forward on a string (the D string as an example), and make a noise that sound something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYTQIIXDrwI). What would be sheet music notation for writing that?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is called a *Portamento*. On sheet music portamento would look like this: [![Portamento](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTVn8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTVn8.png) This portamento indicates sliding fingers from G (On the E string) down to E (Open E string)

Comment: Xilpex - please stop deleting your questions just because you get a downvote. You are likely to trigger automated question bans if you do this.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem I'm so sorry... I didn't know.

Comment: @Xilpex Generally, we reserve deletion for more extreme circumstances, never simply because of downvotes. I like this question (though it's been asked before); I think it belongs on this site. Also, the system itself records self-deleted posts for this very reason, as User Doktor Mayhem has noted. I try never to delete my own posts unless I did something egregious like posting on the wrong site by mistake. The moderation/review queues will handle most minor issues.

Comment: Actually thia is not really a duplicate question, because the other question is about the difference between portamento and glissando while singing. But this question is about how to notate a glissando in sheet music for violin.

Comment: What is the point of asking a question and then posting the answer to your own question in a comment? Your comment is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Sliding the fingers is called 'portamento' and the notation looks like this:
[image]

A glissando is similar but notated with a wavy line. The differences are discussed in this question: [What is the difference between portamento and glissando?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/what-is-the-difference-between-portamento-and-glissando?noredirect=1&lq=1) (the answer with the most upvotes is good, not the accepted one).